# How to allow OPTIONS method from mobile using gorilla handler?

Tags: go, gorilla

Need to accept OPTIONS method coming from mobile device,
attempted multiple ways to do so and getting strange behavior:

when trying this I get 403 from the client:
(client sends `OPTIONS` before `POST`)

```
  import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/users", UserEndpoint)
    r.HandleFunc("/projects", ProjectEndpoint)

    methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"OPTIONS", "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "POST"}

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(methods)(r))
}
```

if I omit the `methods`:

```
        http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS()(r))
```

I get 403 not authorized

Also played around with it, removed the `GET` method:

```
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"OPTIONS"}

http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(methods)(r))
```

but still could 
get a `200 GET` when tried from rest client in browser (chromes DHC)

but if I remove the `OPTIONS`:

```
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "POST"}

http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(methods)(r))
```

I get 405

First example is based on gorilla handler docs

Any ideas on this issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You really need to understand the request being made, but I had a similar problem and resolved it with:

```
handlers.CORS(
        handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}),
        handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"POST"}),
        handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type", "X-Requested-With"}),
    )(router)
```

The request I needed to make (which mimics a preflight) was:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
-X OPTIONS --verbose http://127.0.0.1:8080/products
```

It was really the `AllowedHeaders` func that made all the difference. As soon as I added that, the `403` error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [cors.go](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/master/cors.go#L55) Options are specially handled:

```
corsOptionMethod           string = "OPTIONS"
...

    if r.Method == corsOptionMethod {
        if ch.ignoreOptions {
            ch.h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        if _, ok := r.Header[corsRequestMethodHeader]; !ok {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        method := r.Header.Get(corsRequestMethodHeader)
        if !ch.isMatch(method, ch.allowedMethods) {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
...
```

So 405 is http.StatusMethodNotAllowed, so maybe it is not CORs request header?

There is also an IngoreOptions method for handling Options independely: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#IgnoreOptions - maybe that will work in your case and you can just ignore it, or process Options on your own.

Comment: Isnt ignoring `OPTIONS` and then allowing them in cors options contradicts?